# How do I show the volume control overlay using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, macos, sound-volume

I use BetterTouchTool and Applescript to have hotkeys for specific functions.  For example, I have Command F11 set up to set my Mac's volume to 19, which is basically the same as 3 dashes on the system volume overlay ("set volume output volume 19").  But the overlay doesn't display, and I'd like it to.

How can I trigger the system volume control overlay in macOS Sierra?

Comment: I do not believe there is a way just in AppleScript to cause the volume control overlay to show. Why do you need it to show anyway when `set volume output volume 19` does just that, sets it where you want it.  Add a `beep` afterwards if you want some indication it triggered.

Comment: "Why do you need it to show anyway when set volume output volume 19 does just that, sets it where you want it."  Well, geez, why do any forms of visual confirmation exist?  I'm not only asking for the sake of that one example I gave.

Comment: I had a clever solution I was really proud of, but it turns out it doesn't work either... :(

Comment: That's hilarious because I was thinking the same thing.  I almost decided to make my own overlays.  Sigh.  Maybe I will.